# How to add element with same name using for loop to a list

Tags: dart

I want to add some element with a same name to a List in Dart.

### For example:

```
List<house> home = List<house>();
```

I want to add:

```
home.add(house1);
home.add(house2);
home.add(house3);
```

Is there anyway to add it iteratively like this?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) home.add(house$i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Why do you want to do this?

The behaviour you want to write can't be programmed. A name of a variable is passed to the compiler only for a reference, but once your code is compiled the name `house1` or any other name you choose will be irrelevant. (for example `house$i` (which will be a `String` type) can only be generated at runtime, not at compile time).

You can actually achieve the behaviour you want by writing the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   home.add(new house());
}
```

As mentioned above, the following code will not work. The compiler is smart, but not smart enough to know that you will have 3 instances of `house` with their corresponding name, for example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) home.add(house$i)
var a = house1; // Can't compile. Where can I find house1?
```

However you can always write the following:

```
var house1 = house();
var house2 = house();
var house3 = house();

home.add(house1); // Compiles! Now I know where to find house1!
home.add(house2);
home.add(house3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `n` Objects of `House` & store them in a `List` as follows, instead of creating multiple variables.

```
List<House> home = [House(), House(), House()]; // House() is an object of House.
```

**OR**

```
List<House> home = new List<House>();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) home.add(House());
```